# Java HashMap - variable.getKey - Generic Print Method

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm looking to create a method which will accept a `String` as a parameter and then print out the respective `HashMap` that the `String` refers too.

```
sensorMappings = new HashMap<>();
sensorMappings.put(136, "doorNumber");
```

This is my method to print the `HashMap`:

```
void printHashMap(String mapChoice){
  for (Integer ID : mapChoice.keySet()) {
    String key = ID.toString();
    String value = sensorMappings.get(ID);
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
  }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Can't resolve method 'keySet()'
```

EDIT - full code:

Main.class

```
sensorInfo.printHashMap("mapChoice");
```

Sensor.class

```
public class Sensors {
  private HashMap<Integer, String> sensorMappings;

Sensors(){
  sensorMappings = new HashMap<>();
  sensorMappings.put(136, "doorNumber");
}

void printHashMap(String mapChoice){
  for (Integer ID : mapChoice.keySet()) {
    String key = ID.toString();
    String value = sensorMappings.get(ID);
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
  }
}
```

I have multiple HashMaps and wish to create a generic method to print them by passing in the required HashMap.

Comment: you pass a String not a Map to printHashMap. keySet cannot work.

Comment: could you post the whole code, so that we can try to correct?

Comment: I've added the additional code.

Comment: What is the desired result? Is it different from what you would obtain if you used `sensorMappings.keySet()` instead? The latter should not give any compile errors.

Comment: I have multiple hashMaps and want a generic method to print any of them that have been passed.

Comment: In your main class, you're passing in the parameter "mapChoice".  Would this be the text "sensorMappings" instead, as I don't see how "mapChoice" refers to anything else in your code

Comment: I have multiple HashMaps, I only included sensorMappings here as an example. The parameter "mapChoice" could be "sensoMappings" or any other HashMap name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this if you register all your various hashMaps in another variable keyed by name.  Then you can look up any of the hash maps that you've got registered.

An example would be below.

```
public class MapRegistry {
  static Map<String,HashMap<Integer,String>> allMaps = new HashMap<>();

  public static void register(String name, HashMap<Integer,String> myMap) {
    allMaps.put(name, myMap);
  }

  public static HashMap<Integer,String> find(String name) {
    return allMaps.get(name);
  }
}
```

In your sensors class

```
Sensors(){
  sensorMappings = new HashMap<>();
  MapRegistry.register("sensorMappings", sensorMappings);
  sensorMappings.put(136, "doorNumber");
}
```

Then to look up the particular map:

```
void printHashMap(String mapChoice){
  HashMap<Integer,String> map = MapRegistry.find(mapChoice);
  for (Integer ID : map.keySet()) {
    String key = ID.toString();
    String value = map.get(ID);
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
  }
}
```

You don't need a static class if you are prepared to pass the registry around or can inject it.

You will need to pay attention if you ever remove maps as the registry will keep hold of them.  So you'll need to ensure that the registry is updated as well or you'll get leaks.

Comment: I am getting some errors:
`HashMap map = MapRegistry.get(mapChoice);` - cannot resolve method `get`

`Integer ID` - required Object, foundIinteger

`String value = map.get(ID);` - required String, found Object

Comment: @ColinShewell I've added the parameter types to the printHashMap function.

Comment: I'm still getting the `HashMap<Integer, String> map = MapRegistry.get(mapChoice);` gives the error `cannot resolve method get(Java.lang.String)`

Comment: `.get` should be `.find`

Comment: what would the best way to update the registry if records are modified?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. Java is a strongly typed Language. You have to pass the map and not String to compile it. Maybe you can have a look at the [reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) (not suggested unless you have a string reason to use it).

Comment: "unless you have a string reason to use it" Pun intended ? :-)

Comment: @Tim You got me

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the hashmap at all. You are passing a string. Maybe you are trying to pass a hashmap than a string.

```
printHashMap(sensorMappings);
```

In the print function.

```
void printHashMap(HashMap mapChoice){
    for (Integer ID : mapChoice.keySet()) {
        String key = ID.toString();
        String value = sensorMappings.get(ID);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
}
```

If you are trying to encode the HashMap and convert that back to the string then you can try this

```
String value = sensorMappings.toString();
value = value.substring(1, value.length()-1);           //remove curly brackets
String[] keyValuePairs = value.split(",");              //split the string to creat key-value pairs
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();               

for(String pair : keyValuePairs)                        //iterate over the pairs
{
    String[] entry = pair.split("=");                   //split the pairs to get key and value 
    map.put(entry[0].trim(), entry[1].trim());          //add them to the hashmap and trim whitespaces
}
```

Comment: Looks like OP know this and he is trying to create a generic method.

Comment: Your first code example looks really untested and flawed? How about rechecking it?